# Find tables with columns with empty and NULL values in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, plpgsql, null

After some research I found an example where I can find tables and its columns with NULL values. But the function also returns true when the column is empty. It gives me errors when I try to add an or statement. How can I modify the function so it returns also true when the column contains blank values? This is the function I found:

```
create function has_nulls(p_schema in text, p_table in text, p_column in text)
                returns boolean language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  b boolean;
begin
  execute 'select exists(select * from '||
          p_table||' where '||p_column||' is null)' into b;
  return b;
end;$$;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Please **always** put the version of your server in the question, either as a tag or in the text of the question itself (near the beginning). Help us to help you! :-)

Comment: `WHERE coalesce(col, '') ~ '^[[:space:]]*$'`

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "empty" and "blank values" means empty string (`''`).

This function checks whether the passed table has *any* `NULL` or empty values (`''`) in the passed column (which must be a string type or some other type where the empty string is valid; not the case for numeric types for instance):

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_has_missing(_tbl regclass, _col text, OUT has_missing boolean)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE
   format($$SELECT EXISTS (SELECT FROM %s WHERE %2$I = '' OR %2$I IS NULL)$$, _tbl, _col)
   INTO has_missing;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_has_missing('tablename', 'column')
```

Or, optionally, schema-qualified:

```
SELECT f_has_missing('schema.tablename', 'column')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63aadf09dd44c8d9a5e9c3e29c0338c1)*

Probably most important: Never concatenate parameter values into SQL code blindly. That's begging for SQL injection. I sanitized the code with `format()`. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

There are a couple of smart expressions to check for both:

```
(string_col = '') IS NOT FALSE
(string_col <> '') IS NOT TRUE
coalesce(string_col, '') = ''
```

See:

- [Best way to check for “empty or null value”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23767625/939860)

But I chose this plain and more verbose expression for two reason:

```
string_col = '' OR string_col IS NULL
```

I have grown fond of simple, obvious code, and none of the above is as clear as this. But more importantly, this expression **can use an index** on `(string_col)`, while the above cannot - which makes a big difference for big tables. See the added demo in the fiddle!

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=63aadf09dd44c8d9a5e9c3e29c0338c1)*

Obviously, we want a different name for the function than "has_nulls", now.

I use an `OUT` parameter for convenience and short code. Now we can assign to it and be done.

And I use `regclass` as `IN` parameter for the table name. This way I can provide a schema explicitly or not. Again, see:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

Aside, one might loop through all columns of a table or a whole db to find any such column at once. Related:

- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10686513/939860)
- [Set empty strings ('') to NULL in the whole database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462345/939860)