# Get latest timestamp from column in given table dynamically

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I want to get last timestmap from a table with the column `updated` in PostgreSQL.

And I want a function to do that. So I can pass the table name as parameter and the function returns the latest timestamp in column `updated`.

My table:
[image: table sample]

Query used:

```
select max(updated) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably simplest with `regclass` as input and an `OUT` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_last_update(_tbl regclass, OUT _last_update timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT max(updated_at) FROM ' || _tbl
   INTO _last_update;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_last_update('mytable');
```

Optionally schema-qualified and double-quoted where required:

```
SELECT f_last_update('"My_odd_ScHeMa"."Unwise table name"');
```

Safe against SQL injection because `regclass` is automatically quoted and schema-qualified properly when converted to `text`.

See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)
- [Find tables with columns with empty and NULL values in Postgresql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280724/find-tables-with-columns-with-empty-and-null-values-in-postgresql/280765#280765)
- [Check whether empty strings are present in character-type columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81966/check-whether-empty-strings-are-present-in-character-type-columns/82030#82030)

Comment: it is possible to make another approch ? i want to compare performance and optimisation