# Get another function to return timestamp in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, dynamic-sql

Can I have another function to return the last timestamp.
I want to compare with this query to use the best query.

My query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_last_update1(nomTable text , OUT updated timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT max(updated) FROM ' || nomTable
   INTO updated;   
END
$func$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is insecure and vulnerable to SQL injection:

```
SELECT f_last_update1('sometable; DROP TABLE sometable; SELECT current_timestamp');
```

Use

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_last_update1(
   IN  nomSchema text,
   IN  nomTable text,
   OUT updated timestamp)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
              'SELECT max(updated) FROM %I.%I',
              nomSchema,
              nomTable
           )
      INTO updated;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: how can i add schema

Comment: Like I show in my extended answer.

Comment: i get error see query : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c4929c7d365a68cde6f339348480125

Comment: Well, if the function has two input parameters, you have to call it with two arguments...

Comment: @FranckWhite: My answer to your [duplicate question yesterday](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/289464/3684?) avoids all of these complications  by using `regclass` input.