# Using parameters in stored procedure with plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql, postgis, syntax

I am trying to return the count of overlapping polygons. The problem is that it complains about my "$1" signs:

> ```
> Error is "SQL state: 42601", syntax error at "$1".
> ```

Why is this? I'm a total beginner here and I can't find the solution online, other than that parameters is referenced to with `$` sign.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_overlap (x text) 
RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE amount INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO amount FROM $1 a
    INNER JOIN $1 b ON 
    (a.polygon && b.polygon AND ST_Relate(a.polygon, b.polygon, '2********'))
    WHERE a.ctid != b.ctid;
    RETURN amount AS id;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Is `x` supposed to be a table name? You're passing it as a `text` value, which makes your `SELECT` statements nonsensical

Answer (score 5):

Problems:

1. You cannot parameterize identifiers (like table names) in plain SQL. You need dynamic SQL using `EXECUTE` for this.
2. `amount` is `integer`, but `count()` returns `bigint`.
3. `RETURN amount AS id;` is invalid syntax. To force a particular column name for a returned scalar (not a set-returning function), use an `OUT` parameter. Example:

   - [Get latest timestamp from column in given table dynamically](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/289464/get-latest-timestamp-from-column-in-given-table-dynamically/289511#289511)
4. We are talking about a *function*, not a *stored procedure*. See:

   - [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a "Stored Procedure" and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/in-postgresql-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-other-typ)

This function would work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION any_overlap (_tbl regclass, OUT id bigint) 
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(
   $q$
   SELECT count(*)
   FROM   %1$s a
   JOIN   %1$s b ON a.polygon && b.polygon AND st_relate(a.polygon, b.polygon, '2********')
   WHERE  a.ctid <> b.ctid
   $q$, _tbl)
   INTO id;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT any_overlap ('public.mytable');
```

Be wary of SQL injection when using dynamic SQL! Note the type `regclass` for the passed table name. See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)